# Referencing pointers after a fork() call in C

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, fork

So, I've got a function that loads up a char** variable with some string data. My goal is to fork the process, and print some of that data in the child, and some from the parent. However, I'm unable to reference the pointer after the fork() call.

I thought that fork() made a copy of the entire address space of the parent process, which seems that it would include the various stack pointers...

Essentially, my code currently looks like this:

```
load_data(char **data);

char** data;
load_data(data);
printf("String 0: %s\n", data[0]);
fork(); 
printf("String 0 again: %s\n", data[0]);    /* Segfaults Here! */
```

Anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I've done a bit of google searching on this, and it seems what I'm doing should work - but it doesn't. Thus, I'm misunderstanding something fundamental...

Comment: *"I thought that fork() made a copy of the entire address space of the parent process, which seems that it would include the various stack pointers..."* This is not germane to the question, but at least on most modern UNIX systems, `fork` doesn't copy the entire address space at the time it's called. It uses a *copy-on-write* scheme; the memory pages are copied as soon as they change. It *feels* like memory pages copied at the time of `fork`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing bad pointer operations and just getting lucky on the first call - here's what the code should look like:

```
load_data(char **data);

char* data = NULL;
load_data(&data);
printf("String 0: %s\n", data);
fork(); 
printf("String 0 again: %s\n", data);    /* Doesn't Segfault Here! */
```

Comment: It should be `NULL` all uppercase, by the way.

Comment: This is assuming that the OP's function would be `load_data(char *&)` in C++. Which it probably would be, and the OP's usage is certainly wrong, but there's a chance the OP needs a `char **`.

Comment: I actually do need char**, since I'm working around some existing code and the load_data function is already written for me taking the char**. In my actual use case, data is actually an argv**, which I'll be passing the argv[0] to an execve call. Any tips on making this work in that case?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `data` doesn't point anywhere. **Using an uninitialized variable is undefined behaviour.** Even if it changed inside the load_data function, the change wouldn't be visible outside.

You need to either make `data` point to something valid, or pass the address of `data` to the function to have the changes "return", as in `load_data(char ***data)`.

---

Your code, with minimal changes to make it a complete program, "works" for me

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int load_data(char **data);

int main(void) {
  char **data;
  data = malloc(2 * sizeof *data);
  assert(data && "no memory");
  load_data(data);
  printf("String 0: %s\n", data[0]);
  fork();
  printf("String 0 again: %s\n", data[0]);
  return 0;
}

int load_data(char **data) {
  data[0] = "one";
  data[1] = "two";
  return 2;
}
```

And a sample run

```
$ ./a.out 
String 0: one
String 0 again: one
String 0 again: one
```

Comment: Your code works fine on my system too, but I can't use dynamic memory in this case. I'm not sure what's different between my actual code and yours, other than that... which is part of why I'm so confused.

Comment: Your `data` is uninitialized. See my new comments at the top of my answer.