# what happens to pointers to dynamically allocated memory after a UNIX fork?

Tags: c, unix, fork

Someone please clarify what happens with pointers after a fork().

As I understand it, pointers to anything on the stack or statically allocated are relative to the stack/data segment registers, so copying them exactly during a fork is OK.

However, what happens if I malloc() something before forking? for example:

```
void* p = malloc(64);
// put something in *p;
fork();

// what happens to p and the memory i allocated here?
```

possibilities I am thinking of:

1. *p is copied to some other part of the heap, p is updated to reflect the newly copied location.
2. p still points to the original. if any child runs free(p); the parent may be unable to access it.
3. p still points to the original data, but the child process does not have rights to access/manage the memory.

which of these, if any, is correct?

Comment: Pointers still point to the same memory address. What is updated is the virtual mapping. Pointer -> virtual address -> real physical address.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Referencing pointers after a fork() call in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393933/referencing-pointers-after-a-fork-call-in-c)

Comment: duplicate of [Specifically, how does fork() handle dynamically allocated memory from malloc() in Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597893/specifically-how-does-fork-handle-dynamically-allocated-memory-from-malloc-i)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When forking, child process becomes **a copy** of its parent. That includes any dynamically allocated memory. So the memory will be copied. Pointer address will stay the same (copy doesn't change data, remember?), which is achieved by [virtual addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). Don't forget to call `free` in both parent and child processes.

Comment: thanks. the virtual addressing part is really what I didn't understand.

Answer (score 3):

The value is also copied, as fork copies code, globals, heap and stack.

Source : http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~huangj/cs360/360/notes/Fork/lecture.html

Answer (score 1):

Malloced memory comes from the **heap**, which is just a fancy word for **a set of memory pages**. Since `fork()` copies all of a process's memory pages regardless of any fancy naming they've been given in textbooks, pointers returned by fork() work just fine in the child :-)