# Fork after malloc causing memory leak

Tags: c, memory-leaks, fork, valgrind

I'm working on a system programming project that requires forking N process. The issue is I'm keeping the PID's in a dynamicly allocated array and valgrind with "--leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all" flags shows this PID array pointer as possible leak.

```
pid_t *pid;

//...globals & prototypes

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    //... Input parsing

    // Create actor process=========================================
    pid = malloc((_N + _V + _C + 1) * sizeof(pid_t *)); // LINE VALGRIND IS POINTING STILL REACHABLE
    for (int i = 0; i < _N + _V + _C + 1; i++)
    {
        pid[i] = fork();
        if (pid[i] == 0)
            break;
    }
    // ======================================== Create actor process

    // Parent process ====================================================
    if (parent_pid == getpid())
    {

        // Wait for all the childeren=====================================
        for (int i = 0; i < _N + _V + _C + 1 || exit_requested != 0; i++)
        {
            int status;
            if (waitpid(pid[i], &status, 0) == -1)
            {
                errExit("waitpid");
            }
            
        }
        // =====================================Wait for all the childeren

        // Free resources
        free(pid);

        //.. destroy semaphores

        shm_unlink(SHARED_LINK);
    }

    // Child processes ===================================================
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _N + _V + _C + 1; i++)
        {
            if (i >= 0 && i < _N && pid[i] == 0)
            {
                producer(_I, shared_data, i);
            }
            else if (i >= _N && i < _N + _V && pid[i] == 0)
            {
                mid_consumer(shared_data, i - _N);
            }
            else if (i >= _N + _V && i < _N + _V + _C && pid[i] == 0)
            {
                end_consumer(shared_data, i - _N - _V);
            }
        }
    }
    // ===================================================================
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the valgrind output

```
==8056== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==8056== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==8056== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==8056== Command: ./program -n 2 -v 2 -c 4 -b 81 -t 2 -i cold_storage.txt
==8056== Parent PID: 8055
==8056== 
==8061== 
==8061== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8061==     in use at exit: 72 bytes in 1 blocks
==8061==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 72 bytes allocated
==8061== 
==8061== 72 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==8061==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8061==    by 0x10925D: main (main.c:169)
==8061== 
==8061== LEAK SUMMARY:
==8061==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8061==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8061==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8061==    still reachable: 72 bytes in 1 blocks
==8061==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8061== 
==8061== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8061== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==8059== 
==8059== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8059==     in use at exit: 72 bytes in 1 blocks
==8059==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 72 bytes allocated
==8059== 
==8057== 
==8062== 
==8057== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8057==     in use at exit: 72 bytes in 1 blocks
==8057==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 72 bytes allocated
==8057== 
==8062== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8062==     in use at exit: 72 bytes in 1 blocks
==8062==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 72 bytes allocated
==8062== 
==8059== 72 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==8059==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8059==    by 0x10925D: main (main.c:169)
==8059== 
==8059== LEAK SUMMARY:
==8059==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8059==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8059==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8059==    still reachable: 72 bytes in 1 blocks
==8059==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8059== 
==8059== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8059== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==8062== 72 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==8057== 72 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==8062==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8057==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8062==    by 0x10925D: main (main.c:169)
==8062== 
==8057==    by 0x10925D: main (main.c:169)
==8062== LEAK SUMMARY:
==8057== 
==8062==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8057== LEAK SUMMARY:
==8062==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8057==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8062==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8057==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8062==    still reachable: 72 bytes in 1 blocks
==8057==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8062==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8057==    still reachable: 72 bytes in 1 blocks
==8062== 
==8057==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8062== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8057== 
==8062== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==8057== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8057== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==8063== 
==8063== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8063==     in use at exit: 72 bytes in 1 blocks
==8063==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 72 bytes allocated
==8063== 
==8063== 72 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==8063==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8063==    by 0x10925D: main (main.c:169)
==8063== 
==8063== LEAK SUMMARY:
==8063==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8063==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8063==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8063==    still reachable: 72 bytes in 1 blocks
==8063==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8063== 
==8063== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8063== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==8058== 
==8058== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8058==     in use at exit: 72 bytes in 1 blocks
==8058==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 72 bytes allocated
==8058== 
==8058== 72 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==8058==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8058==    by 0x10925D: main (main.c:169)
==8058== 
==8058== LEAK SUMMARY:
==8058==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8058==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8058==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8058==    still reachable: 72 bytes in 1 blocks
==8058==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8058== 
==8058== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8058== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==8064== 
==8064== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8064==     in use at exit: 72 bytes in 1 blocks
==8064==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 72 bytes allocated
==8064== 
==8064== 72 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==8064==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8064==    by 0x10925D: main (main.c:169)
==8064== 
==8064== LEAK SUMMARY:
==8064==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8064==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8064==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8064==    still reachable: 72 bytes in 1 blocks
==8064==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8064== 
==8064== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8064== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==8060== 
==8060== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8060==     in use at exit: 72 bytes in 1 blocks
==8060==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 72 bytes allocated
==8060== 
==8060== 72 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==8060==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8060==    by 0x10925D: main (main.c:169)
==8060== 
==8060== LEAK SUMMARY:
==8060==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8060==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8060==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8060==    still reachable: 72 bytes in 1 blocks
==8060==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8060== 
==8060== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8060== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==8065== 
==8065== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8065==     in use at exit: 72 bytes in 1 blocks
==8065==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 72 bytes allocated
==8065== 
==8065== 72 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==8065==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8065==    by 0x10925D: main (main.c:169)
==8065== 
==8065== LEAK SUMMARY:
==8065==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8065==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8065==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8065==    still reachable: 72 bytes in 1 blocks
==8065==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8065== 
==8065== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8065== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==8056== 
==8056== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8056==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8056==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 72 bytes allocated
==8056== 
==8056== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==8056== 
==8056== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8056== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I tried freeing the PID array in the forked processes too but it still gives the same error.

Comment: The children "inherit" the `pid`, but never free it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601146/what-happens-to-pointers-to-dynamically-allocated-memory-after-a-unix-fork So it can't be "same" error, it is at least another error. Please show the code where you do free it.

Comment: I don't get the purpose of the `pid[i] == 0` tests in the child processes, especially as the `pid` memory block has not been fully initialized.

Comment: Also, shouldn't the `malloc` be allocating `(_N + _V + _C + 1) * sizeof(pid_t)` bytes (not `(...) * sizeof(pid_t *)` bytes)?

Comment: @EugeneSh. comment has helped, i was freeing the pids in an unreachable line.

Comment: @IanAbbott `pid[i] == 0`check is to make sure the function execute only once in the child process, and you are right about the `pid_t *`

Comment: But most of the `pid[]` array will contain junk for most of the child processes. For example, for the first child, `pid[0]` will be 0 and `pid[1]` will be whatever junk was left by `malloc()`. You could `memset` the whole `pid` array to a non-zero value before the `fork`ing loop, or you could store the child's index number in a variable so that it does not need to search the `pid[]` array at all.

Comment: That is a big oversight on my part, i'll fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but it addresses some concerns.

First, the `pid` array memory block is being allocated with the wrong size based on a multiple of `sizeof(pid_t *)` when it should be the same multiple of `sizeof(pid_t)`. That is a harmless waste of memory if `sizeof(pid_t *)` is greater than `sizeof(pid_t)`, but would be a buffer overrun in the unlike case that `sizeof(pid_t *)` is less than `sizeof(pid_t)`.

Second, the child processes do not free the `pid` array memory block.

Third, the child processes loop through all the elements of the `pid` array memory block looking for `pid[i] == 0`. I believe this is the child process trying to find its own index. However, the `pid` array memory block has not been fully initialized in the child process fork, so there could be more than one element with the value `0`. Besides, there is no need for the child process to use the `pid` array at all if all it needs is its index number which it can determine at the time of the `fork()`.

The version below fixes those issues, but I don't know if it fixes the Valgrind errors.

```
pid_t *pid;

//...globals & prototypes

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int cid;  // child index

    //... Input parsing

    // Create actor process=========================================
    pid = malloc((_N + _V + _C + 1) * sizeof(pid_t));
    for (cid = 0; xid < _N + _V + _C + 1; cid++)
    {
        pid[cid] = fork();
        if (pid[cid] == 0)
        {
            free(pid);
            break;
        }
    }
    // ======================================== Create actor process

    // Parent process ====================================================
    if (parent_pid == getpid())
    {

        // Wait for all the childeren=====================================
        for (int i = 0; i < _N + _V + _C + 1 || exit_requested != 0; i++)
        {
            int status;
            if (waitpid(pid[i], &status, 0) == -1)
            {
                errExit("waitpid");
            }
            
        }
        // =====================================Wait for all the childeren

        // Free resources
        free(pid);

        //.. destroy semaphores

        shm_unlink(SHARED_LINK);
    }

    // Child processes ===================================================
    else
    {
        if (cid >= 0 && cid < _N)
        {
            producer(_I, shared_data, cid);
        }
        else if (cid >= _N && cid < _N + _V)
        {
            mid_consumer(shared_data, cid - _N);
        }
        else if (cid >= _N + _V && cid < _N + _V + _C)
        {
            end_consumer(shared_data, cid - _N - _V);
        }
    }
    // ===================================================================
    return 0;
}
```